# Adding lightbox (or something similar) to ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, lightbox

I need to implement some, let's call it "dialog" in some old ASP.NET project that I took over. It's huge project so I'm not allowed to implement new things.

I have a form on which user can attach up to 3 file attachments, enter some 10-15 fields, and when required fields are filled, submit button get's enabled.

What need to be done is press submit, wait for any possible response for server, and then display some sort of dialog, alert, lightbox which would display short summary and list of correctly uploaded files.

What would be the best approach to do this in ASP.NET?

Comment: well, struggling with lightbox, that's why I've asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Considering jQuery Lightbox is designed for overlaying images rather than HTML I would recommend using [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) or [FaceBox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) instead.